# Editing tags on Test Cases in MTM 2013 & TFS

Tags: microsoft-test-manager, mtm

When using MS Test Manager 2013 there does not seem to be any way of adding/editing tags on a test case. I can however select tags as a column to be displayed in for test cases in MTM.

If I open the test case work item in the TFS web portal, I can add/edit tags on the test case there.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to add tags in MTM without having to flip over to web access every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you update your Test Manager / Visual Studio installation to [the latest Visual Studio Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44921), that should enable the Tags field on your work items.

If I remember correctly, your TFS server also needs to have at least TFS 2013 update 2 installed, but as Microsoft only supports the latest released update, I'd recommend to update to TFS 2013 Update 4.

[image: Test Manager showing Tags field]

Comment: Thank you, I'm installing VS2013 update 4 now, TFS already at update 4... will check in the morning and report back.

Comment: Thanks a million, worked perfectly after VS2013 Update 4 was applied.